# NPM install fails with private repo

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

1. `npm login`.
2. I enter username, password and e-mail --> I'm succesfully logged in.
3. I make change to a package.
4. I run `npm publish` and the (org) package gets published and I can browse it (when I'm logged in) at NPM website.

**5. But when I try to install the same package like: `npm install @my_handle/package_name` I get the error: 404. Not found: @my_handle/package_name@latest**

When I run a: `npm config edit` it contains the following:

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=my_token
@my_handle=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@my_handle:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
always-auth=true
```

When I login to NPM, click Settings and the try to run the package via the green link ">_try on RunKit" --> It is also saying that the package is missing!? What? I have now clicked the "report" button...thus I don't get was is happening?

Comment: why @my_handle/package_name? maybe try just npm i package_name?

Comment: Because that is the standard way to install from a private repo (the package_name could exit in the public NPM aw well)?

Comment: I see, didn't know that. Sorry :D

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The issue was - that I found an old ".npmrc" file in the root of the directory I tried to run the `npm install` from (and it contained an invalid AUTH token). Because I logged into the console and publish worked out fine...I didn't realize this issue before many hours later...